# Как сделать вызов функции после завершения другой?

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот

который день бьюсь с этой проблемой не могу разобрать. Имеем такую ситуацию, функция `task` запускается `каждый день в 23:30` через `schedule`. Нужно сделать так, чтобы сразу после того как отработает функция task , запускались функции в потоке `task2, task3, task4`

```
import schedule
import threading
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

class B:
    def task2(self):
        print("Вызов 1 функции после проверки task")
changer = B('table_2', 'table', 'table_1')

class С:
    def task3(self):
        print("Вызов 2 функции после  проверки task")
check_posts = C('table_1', 'table_2', 'table')

class D:
    def task4(self):
        print("Вызов 3 функции после проверки task")
check_users = D('users_1', 'users_2', 'users')

class A:
    def task():
        print("Начало проверки")
        time.sleep(3)
        print(f"Проверка завершена") #после этого нужен запуск task2 task3 task4

def main():
    bot = A()
    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor()

    schedule.every().day.at("23:30").do(lambda: pool.submit(bot.task))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию **submit**:

```
import schedule
import threading
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

class B:
    def task2(self):
        print("Вызов 1 функции после проверки task")

changer = B()

class C:
    def task3(self):
        print("Вызов 2 функции после проверки task")

check_posts = C()

class D:
    def task4(self):
        print("Вызов 3 функции после проверки task")

check_users = D()

class A:
    def task(self):
        print("Начало проверки")
        time.sleep(3)
        print(f"Проверка завершена")

        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.submit(changer.task2)
            executor.submit(check_posts.task3)
            executor.submit(check_users.task4)

def main():
    bot = A()

    schedule.every().day.at("23:30").do(bot.task)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает. Только в task не нужен self
С ним выдает ошибку TypeError: task() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Рад помочь. Если есть дополнительные вопросы, то не стесняйтесь задавать.
Если данный ответ смог решить Вашу проблему, пожалуйста, пометьте её галочкой, тем самым указав, решение вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

```
import schedule
import threading
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

class B:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        pass
    def task2(self):
        print("Вызов 1 функции после проверки task")
changer = B('table_2', 'table', 'table_1')

class C:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        pass
    def task3(self):
        print("Вызов 2 функции после  проверки task")
check_posts = C('table_1', 'table_2', 'table')

class D:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        pass
    def task4(self):
        print("Вызов 3 функции после проверки task")
check_users = D('users_1', 'users_2', 'users')

class A:
    def task(self):
        print("Начало проверки")
        time.sleep(3)
        print(f"Проверка завершена")
        # добавлен запуск функций task2, task3, task4 в потоке
        pool.submit(changer.task2)
        pool.submit(check_posts.task3)
        pool.submit(check_users.task4)

def main():
    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(4) # количество потоков

    bot = A()
    schedule.every().day.at("23:30").do(lambda: pool.submit(bot.task))

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```